# Perl - Encoding to and from base64

Tags: perl, base64, encode

i ve written the following script to convert files from and to base64.

```
# Setup default mode
my $mode = '';
my $encoding = 'base64';
my $file = '';


GetOptions(
'mode=s'        => \$mode,  # mode = Encode / decode
'help!'         => \$help,      # help message
'encoding=s'    => \$encoding,
'file=s'        => \$file
) or die "Incorrect usage!\n";

if( $help ) {
print "Common on, it's really not that hard.\n";
} else {
print "# Script parameters provided : \n";
print "# Mode set to $mode.\n";
print "# Encoding is set to $encoding\n";
print "# Input File set to $file \n";
}


open(FILE, "$file") or die "$!";
open FILEOT, ">$file.out" or die "$!";  
binmode FILEOT;
binmode STDOUT; 

switch ($mode) {

case "encode" { 

        print "# Encoding file $file to $encoding \n";
        print "# Processing .... \n\n";

        while (read(FILE, $buf, 60*57)) {
            $encoded = encode_base64($buf);
            print $encoded;
            print FILEOT $encoded;
        }
}

case "decode" {
        print "# Decoding file $file from $encoding \n";
        print "# Processing .... \n\n";

        while ( read(FILE, $buf, 60*57 ) {
            $decoded = decode_base64($buf);
            print $decoded;
            print FILEOT $decoded;
          }
       }
```

The encoding part works as intended. The decoding part does not give any output. I gave it an input file of the likes :

```
 My name is John
 I eat pineapples
```

and it gives no output. I think the buffered read may not be required in the case of decoding a file already encoded with this script earlier. I used the above test to produce the base64 encoding version but the reverse gives nothing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You won't get helpful answers to your question unless you post the *real code* that you are running. The line `while ( read(FILE, $buf, 60*57 ) {` has imbalanced parentheses, and I am certain that *none* of that code "works as intended". You must also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write; there is very little point in using `my` unless they are in place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block-wise encode/decode won't work. The encoding will result in a bigger output than necessary, because you restart every 60 * 57 = 3420 bytes, but for decoding, 3420 bytes won't be a complete Base64 block. Look at your result, you'll probably see not completely filled lines ending with some `=` chars.

Here is a short sample with a blocksize of 10 for demonstration:

```
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64);

my $in = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
while (my $block = substr($in,0,10,"")) {
    print encode_base64($block);
}

YWJjZGVmZ2hpag==
a2xtbm9wcXJzdA==
dXZ3eHl6
```

Trying to decode this in blocks of 10 chars will try to decode these strings:

```
YWJjZGVmZ2
hpag==\na2x
tbm9wcXJzd
A==\ndXZ3eH
l6\n
```

The first line correctly translates to `abcdefg`, but the second line is decoded to garbage.

There's a command line tool called `base64` which does excatly the same: Encode and decode Base64 files. You should remove that blockwise processing, encode a file and try to decode it using the command line tool (assuming that it does things right). If this is working, your encode is also working, otherwise your encode doesn't work probably. Make it working and continue to the decoding part.

Answer (score 1):

You sould read about PerlIO layers. Also you are interested in [PerlIO::via::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/PerlIO-via-Base64-0.08/lib/PerlIO/via/Base64.pm#SYNOPSIS) module

```
 use PerlIO::via::Base64 eol => "\n";

 open( my $in,'<:via(Base64)','file.mime' )
  or die "Can't open file.mime for reading: $!\n";

 open( my $out,'>:via(Base64)','file.mime' )
  or die "Can't open file.mime for writing: $!\n";
```